# Vaadin FormLayOut commit issue

Tags: forms, vaadin

In the newest version of Vaadin , we cannot use "Form" component(Deprecated) . So we  have to use "FormLayout" Component .

1. What is the Equivalent for form.commit  in "FormLayout"
2. How can we do the field validation in "FormLayOut"
3. Can we use the deprecated "Form" Component  instead of "FormLayOut"

Answer (score 0):

In vaadin 7 the Form is basically divided in to FormLayout and FieldGroup. The FormLayout is only used to specify the layout of the components, but you could use any other layout instead of it. Binding vaadin fields to object fields is done with FieldGroup.

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.itembinding.html

1. Equivalent of Form.commit() is FieldGroup.commit()
2. You add the validators to the fields and you can catch the exception when calling commit.
3. It is possible, but it will be harder to find support for problems related to it and I guess the new functionality and add-ons are mostly developed for non-deprecated features. Also as with all deprecated functionality, it might be removed in the future, so you might not be able to switch to newer vaadin version anymore if it is.